# Show that $(I-\mathbf x\mathbf y^T)^{-1} = I-\frac{1}{\mathbf x^T\mathbf y- 1}\mathbf x\mathbf y^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, inverse, outer-product

Let $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$ and suppose that $x^Ty \neq 1$. Show that $(I-\mathbf x\mathbf y^T)^{-1} = I-\frac{1}{\mathbf x^T\mathbf y-  1}\mathbf x\mathbf y^T$. Note, I need to compute this directly not as some special case.

We need to show that two things:

1. $(I-x y^T)(I-\frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T) = I$, and
2. $(I-\frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T)(I-x y^T) = I$

By definition.

For (1) I have (EDIT 1)
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}(I-x y^T)(I-\frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T) &= I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T-x y^T + \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^Tx y^T \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T-x y^T\left(\frac{x^T y-  1}{x^T y-  1}\right) + \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^Tx y^T \\ &= I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} \left[x y^T + (x^Ty-1)x y^T - x y^Txy^T\right] \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} \left[x y^T + x^Tyx y^T-x y^T -x y^Txy^T\right] \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1}\left[x^Tyx y^T -x y^Txy^T\right] \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1}\left[x^Tyx y^T -x (y^Tx)y^T\right] \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1}\left[x^Tyx y^T -(y^Tx)x y^T\right]\\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1}\left[x^Tyx y^T -x^Tyx y^T\right] \\ &= I.\end{split}\end{equation}$$

With the help in the comments! I think I got it.

And similar multiplication for (2)...

Comment: Try multiplying the term $-x y^T$ by one, but in the form of $\frac{x^T y-  1}{x^T y-  1}$. You may also need to use that $x^T y = y^T x$, since they are scalars.

Comment: @Joe, I have done ur suggested edits, but still am stuck.

Comment: $x^Ty$ is a scalar. Therefore $xy^T \frac{1}{x^Ty-1} xy^T = \frac{1}{x^Ty-1} xy^Txy^T$.

Comment: if we name $W= x^T y = y^Tx,$  we are told $W \neq 1$  along with $xy^T x y^T = x (y^T x) y^T = x W y^T = W x y^T $

Comment: You all are genius' thank you! Let me know if I got it!

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question, rather than putting the answer in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1), we will use the fact that $\frac{x^Ty-1}{x^Ty-1} = 1$ and $x^Ty = y^Tx$. We also use the fact that $xy^Txy^T = (x(y^Tx)y^T) = (y^Tx)xy^T =y^Txxy^T =x^Tyxy^T $. Obser for (1) we have that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\left(I-x y^T\right)\left(I-\frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T\right) &= I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T-x y^T + \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^Tx y^T \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T-x y^T\left(\frac{x^T y-  1}{x^T y-  1}\right) + \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^Tx y^T \\ &= I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} \left[x y^T + (x^Ty-1)x y^T - x y^Txy^T\right] \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} \left[x y^T + x^Tyx y^T-x y^T -x^Tyxy^T\right] \\ &=I - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1}\left[x^Tyx y^T -x^Tyxy^T\right] \\ &=I.\end{split}\end{equation}$$
For (2) we have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{split}\left(I-\frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T\right)\left(I-x y^T\right) &= I - xy^T - \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^T+ \frac{1}{x^T y-  1} x y^Txy^T \\ &= I. \text{ by (1) calculation}\end{split}\end{equation}$$

Thus, $(I-x y^T)^{-1} = I-\frac{1}{x^T y- 1} x y^T$.